MudBlazer and MudNumericField formatted as a currency input validation issue
I have a MudNumericField input on a form and I cant get it to validate a currency value correctly
In my viewModel I have this definition
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A budget value is required")]
[Display(Name = "Period Budget")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal? Budget { get; set; } = 0M;

Then in my form I have this


<MudStack Row="true">
    <MudNumericField Immediate="false" Label="Period Budget Value" Format="C2" Culture="@_en" T="decimal?" @bind-Value="VenueBudget.Budget" For="@(() =>VenueBudget.Budget)" HelperText="Specify period booking budget" />
</MudStack>



and in my codebehind page I have this for the CultureInfo
public CultureInfo _en = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

Im always getting a formatting error, can anyone see where I'm going wrong ?


That "Please match the requested format" message is a default error message displayed by the browser for the HTMLinput element.
Not entirely related to Blazor/MudBlazor, more so related to HTML elements.

Here's two ways you can get rid of that message.
On the component.
MudNumericField is the wrapper/parent of the underlying input element. You add a title="" attribute to the component. Which will override that message.
<MudNumericField title="" 
    Immediate="false" 
    Label="Period Budget Value"
    Format="C2"
    Culture="@_en"
    T="decimal?"
    @bind-Value="VenueBudget.Budget"
    For="@(() =>VenueBudget.Budget)"
    HelperText="Specify period booking budget" />

On the Form.
You add novalidate="true" on the form.
NOTE: Of course this means that all the elements within the form will not have default browser client-side validation. Not sure how much this will affect your use case.
<EditForm Model="@VenueBudget" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" novalidate="true">
<DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <MudNumericField
    Immediate="false" 
    Label="Period Budget Value"
    Format="C2"
    Culture="@_en"
    T="decimal?"
    @bind-Value="VenueBudget.Budget"
    For="@(() =>VenueBudget.Budget)"
    HelperText="Specify period booking budget" />
</EditForm>

Demo MudBlazor Snippet
